# How to display the data from mySQL in listview in android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview

I can insert data into database but now face the problem that cannot retrieve data from the database and display in listview in android. Here is my coding part for retrieve data. Hope someone can help to solve this, thank you.

```
package com.example.iuum;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;


private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://10.19.229.212/webservice/comments.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "post_id";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

private JSONArray mComments = null;

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forum1a);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    new LoadComments().execute();
}

public void clickbtnWrite(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Forum1a.this, AddForum.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
 */
public void updateJSONdata() {


    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);


    try {


        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);


        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

            // gets the content of each tag
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
            map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);


            mCommentList.add(map);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
 */
private void updateList() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.singelpost, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                    TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                    R.id.username });


    setListAdapter(adapter);


    ListView lv = getListView();    
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



        }
    });
}



public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Forum1a.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        updateJSONdata();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        updateList();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How it doesn't work?

Comment: Error message please, if there is a crash please post log cat trace.

Comment: please show your singlepost.xml layout

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, when i write my comment, it doesn't display it out, just into database only.

Answer (score 0):

Add ListView in activity_forum1a.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Take ListView reference

```
    private ListView mList;
```

Initialize it in onCreate

```
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
```

Take ListAdapter class Refernce

```
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
```

Add setListAdapter method

```
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
    this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
    mList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Change updateList method to

```
    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.test, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                R.id.username });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and perform item click operation outside from the method, by implementing onItemClickListener